# How to create a custom error message when anything in a bash scripts fails?

Tags: bash, error-handling

How can I create a custom error message, without checking the return code of the last command everytime?

I want to log an event to a log file, when the script succeeded or fails (anywhere in the script). Anything like this:

```
# cat /var/log/myscript.log
name: myscript | state: failed | date: 2021-01-18
name: myscript | state: succeeded | date: 2021-01-19
```

Regards

Comment: Research `ERR trap`.

Comment: ... and take a look at `help trap`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!